# lastIndexOf to find 3 consecutive space

Tags: javascript

I want to find 3 consecutive space in a string.
SO far i've tried

```
str.indexOf("   ")
str.match(/\s\s\s+/)
```

none of them worked [both returns 1, and detect single space as 3 space]

`Edit`
Sample Input:

```
  Blah blah 1space  2space   3space      lots of spaceNo space
```

It breaks^ here and detect it as 3 space [FF 4]

Comment: a string with lots of space and words in it !

Comment: Ok... then I can only say, it works for me: `alert("  2 spaces before 3 spaces after   ".indexOf("   "))`.

Comment: can you try it again putting the content in a textarea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex looks close, except you're searching for `\s` (which also matches tabs and newlines), and you're searching for 3+ (not exactly 3). Try using this instead:

```
str.search(/ {3}/)
```

It'll return the index of the first three consecutive spaces (or `-1` if there's no match).

If you want to match three or more spaces, you can use this repetition syntax:

```
str.search(/ {3,}/)
```